# How can I create a React Native Button that saves an array value and the Button state to the device using AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage

I am trying to create a button that changes the text when clicked and it saves a value to an array. I then need to save the state of the button and the array to the device using **AsyncStorage**.

**I have the first part done** (please see Snack link [here](https://snack.expo.io/@aurelius_marcus/asyncstorage-button)) but I am struggling to get the AsyncStorage to work properly. If the button had been clicked once, I would expect that the array has the "item 1" value in it and the button would say clicked. Even if the app is closed and reopened, those values should still remain until the button is clicked again.

I have not found any solutions so far. Is there anyone that has some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is the workflow that you should follow:

- create an object in state (in this.state = {} for classes, or setState() with hooks) for your button's text value
- initialize the above value with the value from AsyncStorage (make sure to add some conditional that if it's empty it returns [])
- also take note of how Asyncstorage is async, meaning you'll have to add 'await' when you're assigning the value
- add some conditional for the text value of your button, whereas it will show a loading icon, (or nothing, doesn't matter) while AsyncStorage is retrieving the initial data
- onPress on your button will change the state value AND the AsyncStorage value (or you can only update the AsyncStorage value when you're closing the page with componentWillUnMount, or useEffect(() => return(--do it here--))

If you're using functional components, it would look something like this:

```
const [textValues, setTextValues] = useState([])

const setInitialValues = async () => {
   const info = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myValues')
   setTextValues(info)
}

useEffect(() => {
   setInitialValues()
   return(
       AsyncStorage.setItem('myValues', textValues)
   )
}, [])

return(
    <View>
        <Button onPress={() => setTextValues(textValues + 1) title={textValues.length === 0 ? '' : textValues[textValues.length - 1]}}
    </View>

)
```

Comment: How would this work without using a functional component?

Comment: Instead of useState you’d use the class equivalent of state. Then instead of useeffect you’d split it into the two lifecycle methods: componentdidmount() and componentWillUnmount(). In the former you’d get the item from asyncStorage and in the latter is where you’d set the asyncStorage value.

Comment: I'm still not able to get it to function correctly. I've included a Snack link in the original post. It functions occasionally but not consistently. I cant figure out why i am not able to get consistent results from asynStorage. I tried including the ComponentWillUnmount() like you mentioned but it did not make a difference.